# Which enemies count in Time Stories - A Prophecy of Dragons?

Tags: a-prophecy-of-dragons, time-stories

In A Prophecy of Dragons, there is a point

> when the scenario is won, when defeated enemies count for victory points

where it mentions enemies counting and mentions a location name that seems vague - does it just mean in the one previous location, or something larger than that?

(It seems like it could be hard to remember beyond the immediately previous encounter, but I wonder if an official answer is out there?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several threads on the BoardGameGeek forum about this problem. The answer here is merely a copy/paste of what is said [there](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1553146/end-game-scoring)

> ! The score card says:
>   You score the following points according to your performance on Linaïs.
>   For each opponent defeated: 3MP.
>
> ! It turns out Linaïs is the name of the planet, not the last dimension.
>
> ! Technically speaking, the rules say: Every time you defeat an enemy you remove him from the location as you won't encounter him there if you come back. So to score you just count all those guys. But only from this run, as they come back to their place in each run.

Comment: Thanks. That makes it clearer. It seems a bit strange, since until you win, you wouldn't know to have counted everyone, though would that mean only the cards at locations that get removed? There are also encounters some of which are with muggers, pickpockets, people who challenge you to contests, etc. Hopefully you actually set those cards aside and can go check them, though I might still wonder which of those were "defeated enemies".

Comment: @Dronz I remember when my group came to the same point, we had of course not removed the card and we could not count the number of defeated encounters. However, my group doesn't really score the points, we just play to enjoy the experience and do not care about our final score. (And we do not play the meta-game using the tokens you win with these points, we just start every new scenario with no bonus).

Comment: Yeah, it's not very important to us either, as it seems to really just amount to a very limited-use boost that we haven't used, but I was curious to know what it meant.